# FUNCTION dbname.functionname does not exist

Tags: mysql

I'm getting the following error:

```
FUNCTION dbname.fnname does not exist
```

when performing the following INSERT statement on a MySQL 5.6 database

```
INSERT INTO `fallimenti` (`annoInserimento`, `pk`, `id`, `nome`, `nomeNormalizzato`, `indirizzo`, `citta`) VALUES ('2015', '12345', NULL, 'TEST', '', 'TEST', 'TEST')
```

The statement

```
SHOW TRIGGERS
```

shows no triggers.

The table definition is

```
CREATE TABLE `fallimenti` (
 `annoInserimento` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2015',
 `pk` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `nome` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
 `nomeNormalizzato` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
 `indirizzo` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
 `citta` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
 `prov` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
 `udienza` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `procedimento` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 `anno` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `dichiarazione` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `tribunale` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
 `curatore` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
 `indirizzoCuratore` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
 `telCuratore` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
 `giudice` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
 `piva` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `dataInserimento` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `attivita` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
 `tipo` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET ascii DEFAULT NULL,
 `pec` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `testo` text NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`pk`),
 UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`,`udienza`),
 UNIQUE KEY `nomeNormalizzato` (`nomeNormalizzato`,`citta`,`annoInserimento`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=149418 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Show your SQL query please.

Comment: Post the insert statement as well. How do you expect us to answer your question without seeing the actual statement?

Comment: Which MySQL version do you use? And please add the table definition for `fallimenti`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the culprit. There was an INSERT TRIGGER that calls a not existent function.

I cannot see this trigger from my database user account because such user hadn't the TRIGGER privilege.

The trigger existed because it was created by Plesk, probably using MySQL root user, during a transfer from another server with official Migration & Transfer Agent. Definitely it was a bug (reported yet) with Plesk which miss to transfer privileges and routines between servers.